# Notepad++ regex Finding a line and replacing it with HTML tags in front of the line at at end of line while maintaining the line's original content

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using find and replace in Notepad++ (with regex), I'm trying to add HTML tags to the beginning of a line and end of a line while maintaining the original content of the line. I can find the start and end of the lines OK, but keeping the original content is where I'm running into issues. (very new to regex).

Comment: Please, show some sample lines and expected result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Search for [`.+` and replace with `<tag>$0</tag>`](https://regex101.com/r/8bAXJW/1) (uncheck `.` matches `\r` `\n`)